# ImageMagick command line character limit

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, histogram

I'm using command line definitions for ImageMagick on Windows to add several hundred coloured rectangles to a blank image (histogram). The length of the commands exceeds the 8192 character limit. I have hundreds of these commands:

```
-fill rgb(188,161,161) -draw "rectangle 1,106 4,19"
```

The ImageMagick documentation says that several commands can be placed in a file, which is then read. When testing, these have to be the same command type, i.e. I'd ahve to create a file for the `draw` commands and one for the `fill` commands. However, the colouring won't work then, as the correct `fill` command isn't linked to the relevant `draw` command.

```
magick -size 1920x108 xc:white -fill @fill.txt -draw @draw.txt hist.png
```

Is anybody aware of a workaround or any other options? I thought having the commands in a windows batch file might work, but this also seems to be limited by the 8192 characters.

Comment: This is just barely a programming problem (IMHO). You might do better looking for an ImageMagick specific developer/users forum.What you describe seems like a bug and something that other users would have complained about so check the dev forums. Maybe there is a omnibus option `-all_cmds` or somesuch?  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [MS link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473):

> On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length
>   of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191
>   characters. On computers running Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows NT
>   4.0, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 2047 characters.

So basically, it is a limitation of command line, not imagemagick. Is it possible that you split your task into two and then combine two images that was produced by these two steps onto one resulting image ?

Comment: Yes, have just done it in stages now. I thought there might be a general workaround for the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that **Magick Vector Graphics** (MVG) better suits your needs:

```
convert -size 1920x1080 xc:gray90 -draw @draw.txt result.png
```

[image]

where the file `draw.txt` contains:

```
fill cyan    rectangle 10,10 1800,400
fill magenta rectangle 10,450 1750,800
fill yellow  rectangle 10,850 1850,1000
```

There are some excellent examples by Anthony Thyssen [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#push_context) and a specification of the available drawing primitives [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php).